# I need to create captions for a carousel so whenever I click on an image the captions that belong to that image show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using the flickity carousel and hosting the content in Sharepoint2013. I have created an image columns, a title column and a description column. The images are pulling correctly, but the carousel captions are not. What is happening is that I am looping through all the items and the title and the description are being pulled at the same time and my intention is that it only shows the title and description for the selected image. The carousel has two sections, one is the main carousel and the other one is the thumb carousel

```
<div id="flickityCarousel" class="carousel carousel-main">
 <div class="flickity-viewport" style="height: 300px; touch-action: pan-y;">
  <div class="flickity-slider" style="left: 0px; transform: translateX(35.98%);">
   <div class="carousel-cell is-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 57.01%;">
     <img src="/FunZone/PublishingImages/PurchasingRiskLunch.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="flickity-viewport" style="height: 100px; touch-action: pan-y;">
 <div class="flickity-slider" style="left: 0px; transform: translateX(40.77%);">
  <div class="carousel-cell is-selected is-nav-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 0%;">
   <img src=" /FunZone/PublishingImages/Port%20everglades.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<section id="captionContainer" class="carouselCaption mb-1">
<h2>Port Everglades Wear Red in Support of AIDS Awareness Month</h2>
<p>​Purchasing and Risk Management Divisions sharing camaraderie at an impromptu lunch - relaxing and restoring.</p>
</section>
```

```
var buildMainCarousel = function (items) {
    var flickitySlider = $('#flickityCarousel');
    var carouselContent;

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        carouselContent = '<div class="carousel-cell">' +
            '<img src=" ' + items[i].Image.Url.replace("http://bc-net", "") + alt="">' + '</div>';
        console.log(carouselContent);
        flickitySlider.append(carouselContent);
    }

};

var buildCarouselNav = function (items) {
    var carouselNavContainer = $('#carouselNav');

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var carouselNav = '<div class="carousel-cell">' +
            '<img src=" ' + items[i].Image.Url.replace("http://bc-net", "") + alt="">' + '</div>';
        carouselNavContainer.prepend(carouselNav);
    }

};

var buildCaptions = function (items) {
    var captionContainer = $('#captionContainer');

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var captions = '<h2>' + items[i].Title + '</h2>' +
            '<p>' + items[i].Description + '</p>';
        captionContainer.prepend(captions);
    }

};

//ajax call
var url1 = "/FunZone/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('funZone')/items";
var handle_ajax = function (url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = data.d.results;
            console.log(items);

            buildMainCarousel(items);
            buildCarouselNav(items);
            buildCaptions(items);


        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("Error: " + data);
        }

    });

};

handle_ajax(url1);
```

Comment: So... which part of this code isn't working?

Comment: The buildCaptions function

Comment: *How* isn't it working? All it's doing is prepending captions, which it looks like it's done successfully.

Comment: As I explained above I need to append only the captions that belong to the image showing.

Comment: It's going to be tough to diagnose without a working demo. Maybe dummy the ajax payload and put up a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @isherwood I created a code pen with the hard coded version to give you a visual of what I did. The idea is that when you click on the thumbs it displays the title and description that belongs to that thumb on the yellow box below. Hopefull this helps.
[Codepen.](https://codepen.io/angelogianopulos/pen/gOYVzGO)